# Logout in my react application not working but working using POSTMAN request

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, express-jwt

I have a an application page with a logout button in react and onClick event it handles the request like this

```
async function logOutHandle(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/logout",{withCredentials: true});
      console.log(response)
      if(response.status===200)
      {
        history('/')
      }
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

  }
```

I am getting logged in to my current page with a logout button and creating the token in this controller like this :

```
const login= async (req,res)=>{
    try {
        const {email,password}=req.body;
        const user= await User.findOne({email});
        if(!user){
            return res.status(404).json({error: "Account not dound"});
        }
        if(user.email == email && user.password==password)
        {
            const payload = {
                user: user.id // Assuming user.id is the MongoDB ObjectId
              };
            const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRATE_KEY, {
                expiresIn: '1h', // Token expiration time
            });
            res.cookie('token', token, {
                httpOnly: true,
                maxAge: 1000 *60*60, // 1 hour
              });
              
              
            res.status(201).json({ token, msg: 'Log in Successful' });
        }else{
        res.status(401).json({error:"Check your password or email"});
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({msg:error});
    }
}
```

I am sending the user id in the payload to authenticate the user on the task I am doing.

I am trying to logout user like this

```
const logout= (req,res)=>{
    try {
        // Clear the token cookie by setting it to an empty string and expiring it immediately
        res.cookie('token', 'none', { expiresIn:5000, httpOnly: true });
        res.status(200).json({ msg: 'Logged out successfully' });
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle any potential errors that might occur during the logout process
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred during logout' });
      }
}
```

The thing is when I am using POSTMAN to send the post request "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/logout" I get a successful response but with react I am getting 401 unauthorized I have checked the CORS and other stuff that may cause the problem but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem isn't on the server side, but rather how you are sending your post request in React. In your post request, you need to include the user's credentials, if any.
For instance:

```
fetch('/api/logout', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  credentials: 'include' // THIS IS NEEDED
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => console.log(data));
```

If the credentials: 'include' part is missing, then the user's cookies won't be included in the request and the server won't be able to authenticate the user.

You also need to make sure that the server is set to allow credentials. If you're using Express with the cors middleware, you can do this:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000', // replace this with your origin 
  credentials: true,
}));
```

This configures the server to accept cookies from your origin.
Thank you.